# Keep logging into DataLogger module after losing device connection

Tags: android, movesense

We want to track some data for water sports, so something that is really important for us is to store information in the DataLogger module. 
We noticed the logger stops approximately one minute after we lose the Bluetooth connection with the device. So, my question is, is there a timeout or something related to the DataLogger module that forces to stop the logger? Is there any way to avoid this behavior? If there is a constant, where is it located? We need to keep logging as much as the storage permits. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using the default app that Movesense sensor comes with (hr_wakeup_app or similar) that goes to power off after 1 minute without Whiteboard/BLE connection. If you flash your sensor with plain_app or some other app that never shuts down  the logging will continue.

We are in process of improving the sample app to take into account the running DataLogger when deciding to go PowerOff, but that is not out yet.

*Full disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*